# how can i add json responce to drop down and when i'm select country display states

Tags: android, android-activity

- My json Response for country is :  `{"search values":[{"id":"1","name":"India"},{"id":"2","name":"srilanka"}],"success":1}`
- country's add to drop down fine.
- my requirement when I'm choose country post the request country "id"(dynamic) and table name(static).
- then I'm get states list, this`({"searchvalues":[{"id":"1","name":"Tamilnadu"},{"id":"1","name":"Kerala"}],"success":1}).`

  **My code is :**

  ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.registration);


      //spinners
      country=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.country);
      state=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.state);
      dist=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.dist);
      mandal=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.mandal);

      //edit text
      uname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
      mobileno=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobileno);
      companyname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.cname);
      village=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.village);
      landmark=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.landmark);
      pincode=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pincode);
      pwd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pwd);
      cpwd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.cpwd);
      dstatus=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.delivery);

      //Button
      submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);

      //adapter for drop down
      adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

      adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

      queue=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

      submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REG_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                  @Override
                  public void onResponse(String response) {

                  }
              }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }){

              };
              queue.add(sr);

          }

      });

      //Getting Country spinnervalues
      StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST, D_URL,
              new Response.Listener<String>() {

                  @Override
                  public void onResponse(String response) {
                      Log.d("response","response => "+response);
                      try {
                          JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(response);
                      JSONArray  jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("searchvalues");
                      Log.d("jsonArray","jsonArray => "+jsonArray);
                       for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                           adapter.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                       }

                      } catch (JSONException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }

                  }

  },  new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
           Log.d("ERROR","error => "+error.toString());
      }
  }){
           @Override
              protected Map<String, String> getParams() 
              {  
               Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                  params.put("table","country");
                  System.out.println("params-------------->"+ params);
                  return params;
              }

      };
      queue.add(stringRequest);

      country.setAdapter(adapter);
    country.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {

          StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REG_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
              @Override
              public void onResponse(String response) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              }
          }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

              @Override
              public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }){

              @Override
              protected Map<String, String> getParams() 
              {  
               Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                  params.put("table","state");
               //   params.put("id",position);
                  System.out.println("params-------------->"+ params);
                  return params;
              }

          };
          queue.add(sr);

      }

      @Override
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


      }
  });
  }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
When you are selecting a country on its item select method write volley request    

country.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REG_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          /**get your states from response and save it in array and pass this array to arrayadapter**/
        }
         //Now setadapter with spinner
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    })



    };
    queue.add(sr);

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


}
});
```

Comment: tq for rplay @payal tuteja ,when i"m selecting a country on its item select method write volley request alredy written , my issue is get selected coutry id from json ...thanks

Comment: store your json data in db and use query to get country id for particular country